# Should my if statement work, is it structured properly?

Tags: php, syntax, operators, if-statement

```
if (file_exists($cachefile) && (time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "login" || "thankyou" || "confirm")
```

Should this code work, operators wise and syntax wise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This part won't work as you (probably) want:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "login" || "thankyou" || "confirm"
```

Firstly, `REQUEST_URI` will never be equal to any of these values - it will have at least an additional `/`. If your script is named `test.php`, REQUEST_URI will contain at least `/test.php` (see below what else it might contain). Take a look at the `REQUEST_URI` variable to see how it is structured.

Also, `REQUEST_URI` is treacherous here: it will contain any additional query strings so it will be possible to confuse the comparison by adding an arbitrary `?name=value` to the URL.

Do a `phpinfo()` to find something more fitting than REQUEST_URI, e.g. `SCRIPT_NAME`.

Secondly, the "or" operations you are doing will be applied to the values before the comparison is done.

You probably want something like this:

```
!in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 
          array("/login.php", "/thankyou.php", "/confirm.php"))
```

Comment: $name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$name_array = explode('.', $name);

is my code for that.

ah wait so it should be $name_array[0] instead. Silly me.

Comment: @Sam I suppose that's just as well. However, the `||` comparison won't work either way, the `in_array()` method shown will. Alternatively, you'd have to do a `!=` comparison on each of login, thankyou, and confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it does, I'd create a method for this kind of "complex" conditions.

The methods body would look something like this:

```
if(!condition1)
  return false;

if(!condition2)
  return false;

if(!conditionN)
  return false;

return true;
```

Edit:
The reason is just readbility, you can name those condition methods appropriately and the methods themself are way more readable than a very long if statement.